# Databricks cli does not show all the files

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition, databricks-cli

I am using Databricks community edition and using Databricks cli for file related operations. When I try to list files using cli, it does not list all files which I see from Databricks web portal.

Here is are the files which I see from web portal

[image]

and below is what I see when I use cli

[image]

I am using .databrickscfg file for connecting to Databricks cluster.

Can anyone help me understand this behaviour.

Comment: What personal access token are you using for CLI?

Comment: I am not using any token as Community edition does not support it. I mentioned my login credentials in cfg file.

Comment: possibly confusion between dbfs and workspace files (`databricks fs ls` vs `databricks workspace list`)? 1. pictures of CLI output are not nice (post text instead) 2. both pics remove all context from top / bottom. Esp first pic, need to see if you're browsing dbfs or workspace.